# Octave 4.0.0 - The GUI does not work

Tags: gui-toolkits

I installed GNU Octave 4.0.0 by compiling from source as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645600/how-to-install-octave-4-0-0-in-ubuntu-14-04/645718#645718). However the GUI does not work - that is, if I click on the Octave Icon, nothing happens. However, when I start Octave from terminal all it's fine, but still no GUI. The same question as been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650396/octave-4-no-gui-some-features-not-installed), but the answers don't seem to solve the issue. I have elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya (64-bit).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've installed Octave in my VM by using the official PPA and it worked like a charm, [take a look](http://i.imgur.com/mhzWYaZ.png).   Is there a particular reason, why you chose to compile Octave by yourself instead of using the PPA? It's a huge application with a lot of dependencies, you are probebly missing some of them.

Comment: have you tried `octave --force-gui`

Answer (score -1):

I've installed the QtOctave that you can find in Software Center in elementary OS Freya and it works normally.